# Jquery extention not working with multiple PHP require

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, require

In my main.php I have something like this.

```
<?php require 'require/display1.php';?>
<?php require 'require/display2.php';?>
<?php require 'require/display3.php';?>
```

Each PHP extension contains something like this:

```
<div class="hover_me">
   <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

and at the bottom of my main.php page.

I have my JS extention.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.hover_me').mouseover(function(){
   alert('Hello!');
});
</script>
```

Everthing is working perfectly fine, ONLY on the require/display1.php and not on the other two PHP extention. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Show us the full generated HTML page that is the result of this.

Comment: check your main.php output html

Comment: What should I check there? Can you be more specific?

Comment: in console is there any error?

Comment: can you update your question with the content of main.php as shown in the browser? (i.e. the generated html & javascript).

Comment: Ok, what you need to do is when you open the page in your browser, click `view source`. The press `[ctrl]+A` then `[ctrl]+c`.  Next, you want to click `edit` on your question, and go to the bottom.  Once the cursor is at the bottom press `[ctrl]+v`, and then select everything that was just added.  After it is selected press `[ctrl]+k`.  After that, we _might_ be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try in when document ready

```
$(function() {
   $('.hover_me').mouseover(function(){
      alert('Hello!');
   });
});
```

Comment: Nope, everything is running quite well

Comment: I didn't guess/find out what wrong there. mouseover the second div and see the console